# What is happening to this line in the For Loop?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

Code:

```
Dim answer As Integer
Dim startNumber As Integer

answer = 0

For startNumber = 1 To 4
    answer = answer + startNumber
Next startNumber

MessageBox.Show(answer)
```

Can someone explain the line that says `answer = answer + startNumber`?

I don't understand is `answer = answer`? Why not just `Answer + Startnumber` I have already given the variable `answer` a value of 0. I understand what it's doing it's only that bit of syntax that I can't get my head around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone explain the line that says `answer = answer + startNumber`?

The line `answer = answer + startNumber` is assigning the value of `answer` plus `startNumber` back to `answer`. An alternative way would be `answer += startNumber`.

If you did `answer + startNumber` then you would not retain the previous value of `answer`. Instead you would just overwrite with `startNumber` on each loop.

Consider the following code:

```
For startNumber = 1 To 4
    answer = startNumber
    Debug.WriteLine("answer = " & answer.ToString())
Next startNumber
```

Output:

```
answer = 1
answer = 2
answer = 3
answer = 4
```

Notice how `answer` does not retain it's previous value. Instead all you are doing is setting `answer` with the value of `startNumber`. Now let's try your code:

```
For startNumber = 1 To 4
    answer = answer + startNumber
    Debug.WriteLine("answer = " & answer.ToString())
Next startNumber
```

Output:

```
answer = 1
answer = 3
answer = 6
answer = 10
```

Notice how `answer` now retains it's number before adding `startNumber` to it.

Since you are new I would strongly recommend on learning how to debug your code and analysing the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a for loop. `answer` is assigned whatever `answer` is plus `startNumber` (Which will be 1 on loop 1, loop 2 on loop 2, etc...). Let's break down the loops:

Loop 1 (0 is currently the answer):

```
answer = 0 + 1
```

Answer is now 1

Loop 2:

```
answer = 1 + 2
```

Answer is now 3

Loop 3:

```
answer = 3 + 3
```

Answer is now 6

Loop 4:

```
answer = 4 + 6
```

Answer is now 10

Answer (score 0):

That's not part of the `For` loop per se.  That's the action that is being performed on each iteration of the loop.  The point of a loop is to allow you to do the same thing multiple times.

That thing can be anything and in this example they've just chosen that as a dummy action.  It doesn't really do anything that you'd normally consider useful.  It just exactly what you think it does, i.e. it adds the value of `answer` to the value of `startNumber` and stores the result in `answer`.  That means that the value of `answer` starts at 0 and then becomes 1, 3, 6 and 10 through successive iterations.

If you were writing a `For` loop yourself, you'd put something inside the loop that was useful to you.  For instance, if you wanted to output the 10x tables then you would multiply 10 by the loop counter and output the result.